# How do I tell Bedtime that I am awake?

Tags: iphone, ios, alarm

I use iOS Bedtime as my morning alarm to wake up.  Sometimes I wake up before the alarm goes off.  How do I tell Bedtime that I'm awake and that I don't need to be woken that morning?

The only method I've been able to come up with is to go into the alarm set up and turn the Bedtime alarm off.  However, this turns it off not only for today, but permanently for all future days as well, and I have to remember to re-enable it before the next morning.  It's easy to forget, so that's not good.  Is there a better way to do this, while using Bedtime?

If I don't turn the alarm off when I wake up early, then sometimes I go shower, and the alarm starts ringing while I'm in the shower and I don't notice until I'm out of the shower, which isn't good -- it disturbs others.

Comment: I highly recommend you try this app called **Sleep cycle**. I love the way it handles snoozing and waking up in general. By default it uses "intelligent" wake up time of 30 minutes: it tries to wake you up when you're in light sleep. It allows snoozing right up to when it's time to wake up. When the alarm rings, if picking up the phone shuts if off (or gently nudging it) you can continue snoozing, but when it's time to wake up, you have to unlock the screen and swipe up to turn the alarm off. The philips hue integration is pretty amazing too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to get what you're looking for other than what you're already doing.

Bedtime is made-up of two parts: Bedtime and Wake Up.

These are very easy to use but also very limited.  It's not really designed, unfortunately, for one-off changes to the schedule.

I would recommend looking for a custom Shortcut that you can run to turn off the alarm when you wake up early.  You can try [Routine Hub](https://routinehub.co/) and the [Reddit Shortcuts sub](https://www.reddit.com/r/shortcuts/).

Comment: Thanks!  The following claims one can't do this with Shortcuts, either: https://www.reddit.com/r/shortcuts/comments/bqvq81/is_there_already_or_can_someone_create_a_shortcut/.  Oh well.

Comment: That's unfortunate.  Maybe things have changed in iOS 13?